How to connect React Native Expo App to a backend ASP .NET Core API running locally?
I am making this hobby project where I want to make an App for pinging others in a group about some kind of event happening (it's for League of Legends gaming purpose lol).
I try to connect my Expo App to my locally running .Net Core API. I am running it on Windows and the same Wi-Fi. I've tried both https and http request from my phone to my app but neither work. The request doesn't even seem to get into the server, though I am not sure how to check if that's true.
I guess I need some help with setting up the server so that I can make requests into it.
I paste my request code below.
async function getAllUsers() {
console.error("Fetching data");

const response = await fetch(
"http://localhost:5225/LoLCaller/get-all-users",
{
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
});

 const data = await response.json();
 console.log(data);
 return data;
}

in the code I change the localhost to my local pc's IP that I don't want to share here :D
Thanks a lot for any help!

You can use ngrok to forward your server's local address to some other address.
Use:
ngrok http 5225
it'll give you a URL, which you can use it as your server's address.

Hey, the idea doesn't seem bad but I struggle to make it work. I tried making request through the App, through the web and also through Postman, but it all just neverendingly "loads" and I don't even get any response.
my ngrok works well though, I get this in cmd :
GET /LoLCaller/get-all-users   307 Temporary Redirect

My idea is that maybe my firewall or some security settings are blocking the connection?

Okay, I managed to make it work somehow :D
It seems I've had some problems with setting up ngrok but eventually made it through :D Thanks so much for the help :)
